# how to iterate variable inside push() mehod in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have an array

> array=[];

what i did was

```
 for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
    array.push(console.log({'events['+i+']':'<span id="events['+i+']"></span>}))
    }
```

i want result like this

```
 array=[{events[0]:'<span id="events[0]"></span>'},{events[1]:'<span id="events[1]">/span>'},...];
```

i know it's very silly question to ask but i can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var obj;
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    obj = {};
    obj['events[' + i + ']'] = '<span id="events[' + i + ']"></span>'
    array.push(obj)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FUneV/)